# at the end of the shopping in my project receipt is generated but i need that receipt to be sent to customer and the adim i need php code for that

Tags: php, mysql

i have built a shopping cart it is working well. But i want to do some upgrades like "at the end of the shopping process in my project, receipt is generated but i need that receipt to be sent to customer and the admin, I need php code for that.
The receipt code as follows

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$User = $_SESSION['username'];
}

else
{
$User = "";
}

$date = date("l, d F, Y");

?>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['code']))
{
$code = $_SESSION['code'];
}

else
{
$code = "";
echo "<script>alert('Transaction Error Occured')</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}   
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Order Confirmation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminstyle.css">
</head>
<body>

<p align="right"><a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<p align="center"><img src="image/logo.png" /></p>
<p align="center"><b><u>ORDER CONFIRMATION RECEIPT</u></b></p>

<?php

include("includes/mysqli_connection.php");

$today = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $userid";

$query = (mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $surname = $row['surname'];
    $uname = $row['username'];
    $pass = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $tel = $row['tel'];
    $type = $row['ac_type'];
    $status = $row['user_status'];  
 }
 ?>

 <p align="left"><b> DATE : <?php echo $date;?></b></p>

 <table border="0" width="auto">
 <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
    <td width="25%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="3%"><b>:</b></td>
    <td width="auto"><?php echo strtoupper($surname); ?> <?php echo strtoupper($name); ?></td>
</tr>

  <tr>
  <td width="25%"><strong>Email</strong></td>
  <td width="3%"><b>:</b></td>
  <td width="auto"><?php echo $email; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="25%"><strong>Billing Address</strong></td>
  <td width="3%"><b>:</b></td>
  <td width="auto"><?php echo $address; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="25%"><strong>Telephone</strong></td>
  <td width="3%"><b>:</b></td>
  <td width="auto"><?php echo $tel; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />

<?php
include("adminarea/includes/mysqli_connection.php");

$today = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart , jewellery, users WHERE cart.cust_id = $userid AND users.user_id = $userid AND cart.checkout = 'y' AND jewellery.id = cart.jewel_id AND cart.checkedon = '$today' AND cart.trans = '$code'";

$query = (mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql));

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

// Here we have the total row count
 $rows = $row[0];

    $countrows = $rows;

$totalquantity = 0;

$subtotal = 0;

$totalamount = 0;

$delivery = 500;

$selectproducts = "SELECT * FROM cart , jewellery, users WHERE cart.cust_id = $userid AND users.user_id = $userid AND cart.checkout = 'y' AND jewellery.id = cart.jewel_id AND cart.checkedon = '$today' AND cart.trans = '$code'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $selectproducts);

$list = "";
$src = "Photos/";

if($rows == 0)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Error Occured!')</script>";
    //echo "<script>header(location='index.php');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}

else
{
    echo "<table align='center' outerborder='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' width='50%'>
            <tr><td colspan='5'><hr></td></tr>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='e6e6e6'>JEWEL ID</th><th align='center' bgcolor='e6e6e6''>PRODUCT</th>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='e6e6e6''>QUANTITY</th><th align='center' bgcolor='e6e6e6''>PRICE</th>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='e6e6e6''>AMOUNT</th>";

    for($loop = 0; $loop < $countrows; $loop++)
    {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $jewelid = $row['jewel_id'];
            $qty = $row['qty'];
            $userid = $row['cust_id'];
            $checkout = $row['checkout'];
            $added = $row['added'];
            $checked = $row['checkedon'];

            $prodname = $row['prodname'];
            $path = $row['path'];
            $category = $row['category'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $desc = $row['descr'];
            $width="150px";
            $height="150px";

            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $surname = $row['surname'];
            $uname = $row['username'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $address = $row['address'];
            $tel = $row['tel'];
            $type = $row['ac_type'];
            $status = $row['user_status'];


            $amount = ($qty * $price);

            $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $qty;
            $subtotal = $subtotal + $amount;
            $vat = round(0.15 * $subtotal);
            $totalamount = ($subtotal + $vat + $delivery);

            $amount = round($amount);
            if (round($amount*10) == $amount*10 && round($amount)!=$amount) $amount = "$amount"."0"; //to avoid prices like 17.5 - write 17.50 instead
            {
                if (round($amount) == $amount) //add .00
                {
                    $amount  = "$amount".".00";
                }
            }

            $list ="<tr align='center'><td>" . $jewelid . "</td><td>" . $prodname . "</td><td>" . $qty . "</td>";

            $list .= "<td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $amount . "</tr>";

            echo $list; 
        }
    }
}
    ?>
    <tr>
<td colspan="5"><hr></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
<td colspan="3" rowspan="7"></td>
<td align="left"><font face="monotype corsiva"><b>Total Quantity</b></font></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $totalquantity;?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
<td align="left"><b>Total Items</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows;?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
<td align="left"><b>Sub Total</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $subtotal;?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>VAT (15%)</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $vat;?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Delivery Cost</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $delivery;?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="5"><hr></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Total Amount (Rs)</b></td>
<td align="center" style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:5px"><?php echo $totalamount;?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php mysqli_close($db_conx); ?>
<br />
<center>
<p>THIS IS SERVED AS YOUR OFFICIAL RECEIPT</p>
<p>THANK YOU FOR CHOSING Jewellery</p>
<p><b>NOTE: Expect a phone call confirmation before the delivery</b></p>
</center>

<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
    <script Language="Javascript">function printit()
    {
        if (window.print)
        {
            window.print() ;
        }

        else 
        {
            var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
            WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 2);//Use a 1 vs. a 2 for a prompting dialog box    WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
        }
    }
    </script>

    <script Language="Javascript">
        var NS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape");
        var VERSION = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);

        if (VERSION > 3)
        {
            document.write('<form> <input type=button value="Print this Page" name="Print" onClick="printit()"> </form>');
        }
    </script>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No one here is free enough to write a code for you... So firstly at-least try it yourself..

Comment: `I need php code for that.`: You also need our paypal information? :)

Comment: i have tried this receipt code is fully functional 100% working but my issue is i do not know the logic how to send this receipt to user

Comment: i need code for that